# How to request Qt Creator to execute an additional step after build?

Tags: qt, gprof

I'm experimenting with gprof and [Gprof2Dot](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) which gives me a [graph](http://wiki.jrfonseca.googlecode.com/git/gprof2dot_small.png), produced by the command

```
gprof path/to/your/executable | gprof2dot.py | dot -Tpng -o output.png
```

Development is going on Qt Creator. So came the question: How to request Qt Creator to execute the above command as an additional step after build?

Answer (score 1):

Under "Projects"

[image]

Select the "Build And Run" tab

[image]

This contains the "Build Steps" section, which allows you to "Add Build Step"
[image]

Comment: I did  it, and the executable was called as I was expecting but in the end a "error: unexpected end of file" was shown and the graph wasn't generated.

Comment: Try putting the command in a script file and call the script from the build step.

Comment: Great. Please mark the question as answered by selecting the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: I'm also plotting the results of *running* my application, so I was looking for a post-Run step unlike the OP.  This is a "Build Step" and is before "Run" rather than a post-"Run" step, but I found that I could approximate what I wanted by adding the run command as a 1st custom build step and adding my plot command as a 2nd custom build step.  Thanks!